# how to determine if a numpy array or pandas row contains a string?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas df of floats, but due to improper output/errors from the program from which I received the data, a number of rows contain values that are actually strings.

I want to remove these rows from the df with minimal looping. Ideally, I would like to mask all values in the df to those which are strings, and drop the row with True values. Another would be to iterate through each row and mask each individual row and delete if a True is in the mask. Worst case would be to loop over each row and also loop over each value to achieve the same task.

Can anyone advise how I could do this the most efficiently?

Something akin to df.iloc[x].istype(str) or something?

I tried df.loc[row_num].**contains**(str) as a futile attempt but didn't work.

I know I can loop over every single cell and do isinstance(cell,str) to check if it's a string but would really prefer some kind of masking technique.

As a side note to narrow down any solutions, I don't want to fix any string values to be floats, I just want to delete the entire row.

Thanks in advance.

Example of problematic row is below, notice the string with two decimals:

```
df.loc[516].values

array([890.0, 33.17, 29.64, 78.355, 80.182, 83.196, 86.721,
       90.12299999999999, 92.807, '91.705.099', 98.89, 99.007,
       99.34200000000001, 99.337, 100.43799999999999, 99.867, '100.625',
       100.712, 100.46, 100.427, 101.16799999999999, 100.904, 100.193,
       100.255, 100.537, 100.37100000000001, 100.535, 100.584, 101.52,
       101.787, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Does the dataframe contain one column? Or a column for each value?

Comment: df is many rows with columns for each value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `map` and check type `str`

```
df.loc[516].map(type).eq(str).any()
```

It will return `True` if any cell in row `516` is type `str`

If you want to check whole `df`, just use `applymap`

```
df.applymap(type).eq(str).any(1)
```

It will return a series mask `True/False` for each row

Answer (score 2):

You could transpose the dataframe, then try to convert each column (which was originally a row) using the pd.to_numeric(). If there is a parse error because of a string that cannot be converted to an int or float, it will throw a ValueError. You can catch this exception and delete that column. Something like this:

```
df_transposed = df.T

for col in df_transposed:
    try:
        df_transposed[col] = pd.to_numeric(df_transposed[col])
    except ValueError:
        df_transposed = df_transposed.drop(columns=[col], axis=1)

df = df_transposed.T
```

Comment: Did you test this? On pandas 0.25.1 it just converts strings like '2' to numbers like 2.0, but the OP said **I don't want to fix any string values to be floats**.

Comment: @Stef Yes, I tested this on pandas version 0.24.1, it removes the rows that contain strings.

Comment: @Stef To clarify, it removes the rows that contain strings **that cannot be correctly converted to an int or float**. In other words '8.0' will be converted to a float, but '8.0.3' will cause the row to be deleted.

Comment: this is not exactly what I wanted as it does maintain values that can be converted correctly which I do  not want - however I may explore this to attempt to keep as much data as I can if I can verify it's still good

Answer (score 1):

Using [`isreal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html) and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) we can select all rows where all elements are real, i.e. int or float:

```
df[df.applymap(np.isreal).all(axis=1)]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,'2',3], 'b': [10,20,np.nan]})
df = df[df.applymap(np.isreal).all(axis=1)]
```

gives

```
   a     b
0  1  10.0
2  3   NaN
```

(caveat: this will filter out complex numbers too although they are numeric of course)

Comment: thank you for your answer...this works great but I could only accept one answer -  Andy L's answer seems more intuitive (to me) - :) gave you an upvote though

Comment: no problem, and I admit that excluding any `str` type elements is closer to your question than including any numeric type elements